# How do I construct an instance of a DST struct whose size is only known at runtime?

Tags: rust, struct, unsafe, variable-length-array, dynamically-sized-type

I have a struct that can be used in a fixed-size or unsized way, where the last element is an array of `u8` items.  We can write the following struct definition:

```rust
struct MyStructImpl<E: ?Sized> {
    field: char,
    extendable: E,
}
type MyStructFixed<const N: usize> = MyStructImpl<[u8; N]>;
type MyStructUnsized = MyStructImpl<[u8]>;
```

It is possible to acquire a handle to a unsized version of this struct if we know the size at compilation time.  For example:

```rust
impl MyStructUnsized {
    fn new_from_fixed_array<const N: usize>(field: char, arr: [u8; N]) -> Box<Self> {
        Box::new(MyStructFixed {
            field,
            extendable: arr,
        })
    }
}
```

However, I can't find a way to construct the struct if you only know the size at runtime.  For example:

```rust
impl MyStruct<[u8]> {
    fn new_from_slice(field: char, arr: &[u8]) -> Box<Self> {
        todo!(); // help!
    }
}
```

In theory this should be possible to do: We just need to allocate some space of the correct size, then construct the struct in there, and finally copy the `u8`s over.  `Box<T>` is supposed to know how to free an unsized `T`, so this shouldn't be a problem.

However, in practice, this is not at all simple to do in Rust.  (This is very simple to do in C or C++, owing to the fact that struct layout in those languages is pretty well-defined.)

`std::boxed::Box` has `from_raw()`, which takes ownership of a `*mut T` and puts it in a Box.  An allocated `*mut T` can be gotten from a call to `std::alloc::alloc()`.  However, `std::alloc::alloc()` needs a `std::alloc::Layout`, which is essentially a size and an alignment, but there seems to be no way to calculate the size and alignment of a `MyStructFixed<N>` if `N` is only known at runtime, since the layout of a regular `#[repr(Rust)]` type is unspecified.  In theory the compiler should know it, since it needs to emit code for any member functions of MyStructUnsized, so it would seem reasonable for a compiler intrinsic with the following signature to exist:

```rust
fn get_layout<T: ?Sized>(len: usize) -> Layout;
```

However, I can't find such a thing.

I think something like this might work:

```rust
fn guess_required_layout(len: usize) -> Layout {
    Layout::from_size_align(
        std::mem::size_of::<MyStructFixed<0>>() + len * std::mem::size_of::<u8>(),
        std::mem::align_of::<MyStructFixed<0>>(),
    )
    .unwrap()
}
```

... but that makes an assumption about the layout of extendable structs, which seems to not be meant to be guaranteed.

What is the idiomatic way to construct a Box of an unsized struct whose size is only known at runtime, ideally with the latest stable Rust (1.74.0 at the time of writing)?

Comment: Besides the answer below, you could (technically) use the unstable `std::ops::CoerceUnsized` trait to first construct a sized (!) `[u8; N]`-version of your type and then unsize that to yield the desired `[u8]`-version. Construction would require to have a well-defined `N`, however, and this being part of the type before unsizing makes the whole operation cumbersome (and somewhat pointless). The basic problem remains unsolved here: one needs to dance around properly allocating the struct containing `E` (as shown below). Rust _really_ likes to simply put this behind an indirection via `Box[u8]`.

Answer (score 2):

Custom DSTs are a half-baked feature.

On stable, AFAIK, the only way is to mark the struct `#[repr(C)]`. Then you can calculate the layout manually like:

```rust
use std::alloc::Layout;
use std::ptr::addr_of_mut;

#[repr(C)]
struct MyStructImpl<E: ?Sized> {
    field: char,
    extendable: E,
}
type MyStructFixed<const N: usize> = MyStructImpl<[u8; N]>;
type MyStructUnsized = MyStructImpl<[u8]>;

impl MyStructUnsized {
    fn new_from_iterator(field: char, arr: &[u8]) -> Box<Self> {
        let layout = Layout::new::<char>()
            .extend(Layout::for_value(arr))
            .unwrap()
            .0
            .pad_to_align();

        unsafe {
            let data = std::alloc::alloc(layout);
            if data.is_null() {
                std::alloc::handle_alloc_error(layout);
            }

            let data =
                std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts_mut::<u8>(data, arr.len()) as *mut MyStructUnsized;
            addr_of_mut!((*data).field).write(field);
            addr_of_mut!((*data).extendable)
                .cast::<u8>()
                .copy_from_nonoverlapping(arr.as_ptr(), arr.len());

            Box::from_raw(data)
        }
    }
}
```

On nightly, you could in theory do slightly better with [`Layout::for_value_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/alloc/struct.Layout.html#method.for_value_raw), however, one of its safety precondition is that the size of the entire thing will fit in `isize`, and to calculate that to know the size of the prefix of the DST, which is the fields (known, size of `char`) but also the padding, and you can calculate the padding via the size of the whole struct but then we're back to point one, or you can calculate it via `offset_of!()` of `extendable`, but [`offset_of!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/macro.offset_of.html) is unstable and doesn't currently allows DSTs, and while [there are crates to implement it on stable](https://docs.rs/memoffset) they don't support unsized structs... So in conclusion I'm not sure the hassle is worth it.

Comment: I would note that fitting in `isize` is not _that_ difficult to accomplish, because you don't need the exact size -- which would require knowing the exact value of the padding -- and can instead make do with an over-estimation. For example, as long as the header itself is less than `isize::MAX / 2`, and the slice itself is less than `isize::MAX / 2`, you're golden.

Comment: @MatthieuM. But in theory you've got no guarantee that the header is not bigger than that. I agree, it seems convoluted, but I still wouldn't want to rely on this.

Comment: You can measure the header by creating a 0-length instance. That is, instantiate `MyStructImpl<[T; 0]>` and ask the compiler to give you the size. You'll get size of header + padding (because `[T; 0]` may have 0 size, but it doesn't have 0 alignment) in one fell swoop.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, I've just realized that.

Comment: We seem to be relying on that fact that the additional info (length) in a `&MyStructUnsized ` stores the number of elements in the `extendable` field, is that guaranteed?  Presumably it could store the total number of bytes in the struct?

Comment: @Bernard I remember it was not guaranteed but recently FCP'ed, let me see if I can find it...

Comment: What does FCP mean?

Comment: @Bernard Final Comment Period. It's a process in which the Rust teams decide things about Rust.

Comment: @Bernard It appears it is not guaranteed, and relies on two PRs: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/117474, https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/pull/1206. Although I think this is unlikely to change.